# Arithmetic overflow or other arithmetic exception occurred solution?

Tags: sql, db2, aggregate-functions

I'm using db2, not sure what version.  I'm getting an overflow error when trying to sum a table.  I thought that I would be able to cast the sum to a BIGINT which seems to work for a sum total but I'm looking to get a percentage and when I cast to a BIGINT my data is inaccurate.  How do I get an accurate percentage for Percent_DeliveredB/A?  Converting the numerator and denominator to BIGINT and dividing for percentage is not giving me the correct results.

Here's my script:

```
SELECT 
FAT.DIM_BUILDING_ID,
FAT.BUILDING_NAME,
SUM(CAST(FAT.AMOUNT AS BIGINT)) AS SALES_SUM,
SUM(CAST(FAT.ORDERS AS BIGINT)) AS ORDERS_SUM,
SUM(CAST(FAT.CAPABILITY AS BIGINT)) AS CAPABILITY_SUM,
SUM(FAT.ORDERS_B)/sum(FAT.Amount) AS Percent_DeliveredB,
SUM(FAT.ORDERS_A)/sum(FAT.Amount) AS Percent_DeliveredA,
SUM(CAST(FTS.GROUP_A AS BIGINT)) AS GROUP_A,
SUM(CAST(FTS.GROUP_B AS BIGINT)) AS GROUP_B,
SUM(CAST(FTS.GROUP_C AS BIGINT)) AS GROUP_C  

FROM ORDERS AS FAT
INNER JOIN GROUPS AS FTS ON FAT.DIM_PROJECT_ID = FTS.DIM_PROJECT_ID
GROUP BY FAT.DIM_BUILDING_ID, FAT.BUILDING_NAME;
```

I tried the following but it comes back with 0 for the percentage.

```
SUM(CAST(FAT.ORDERS_B AS BIGINT))/sum(CAST(FAT.Amount AS BIGINT)) AS Percent_DeliveredB
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I edited my question.  Hopefully it's more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the correct results converting to double.

```
SUM(CAST(FAT.ORDERS_B AS DOUBLE))/sum(CAST(FAT.Amount AS DOUBLE)) AS Percent_DeliveredB,
```

Answer (score 2):

It is giving you a correct result, as any value less than 1, when cast to an integer (or BIGINT for that matter) will be truncated to 0, obviously. If you are expecting a fractional number, use DECIMAL or FLOAT data types:

```
cast(SUM(FAT.ORDERS_B) as decimal(10,2)) / 
cast(sum(FAT.Amount) as decimal(10,2)) AS Percent_DeliveredB
```

Use the correct precision for your needs, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error while using a `select count(*)` on a very big table.

I solved it by using `count_big(*)` which can handle a count that is more than 2.147.483.647 (the `MAX_LONGINT_INT SQL` limit).